# How to write cases in Markdown equations

Tags: markdown, mathjax

How can I write something like this in markdown?

[image]

Here are the specific things I don't know how to do:

- The big curly brace with two lines
- If it's required after I know the above, the tab separation within the two lines

Here's what I would do if I knew the right syntax:

```
$$
CE(p, y) = \curlytwo{-\log(p) \tab \text{if }y=1}{-\log(1-p) \tab \text{otherwise.}}
$$
```

where I've invented `\curlytwo` and `\tab`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use the `cases` environment to write cases which is [supported in MathJax](https://www.onemathematicalcat.org/MathJaxDocumentation/TeXSyntax.htm#environments):

```latex
$$
\mathrm{CE}(p, y) = \begin{cases}
    -\log(p) & \text{if } y = 1 \\ % & is your "\tab"-like command (it's a tab alignment character)
    -\log(1-p) & \text{otherwise.}
\end{cases}
$$
```

Answer (score 0):

```
\begin{equation}
(p, y) = 
\begin{cases}
    -\log(p) & \text{if }~~ y = 1 \\
    -\log(1-p) & \text{otherwise.}
\end{cases}
\end{equation}
```

Answer (score 0):

I learned from [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference/6267#6267) and used array.

```
$$
CE(p,y)=\left\{
\begin{array}{ll}
-\log(p) &\text{if }y=1 \\ 
-\log(1-p) &\text{otherwise}.
\end{array} 
\right.
$$
```